# How to extract information from XmlObject in JAVA without using toString()?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have an XmlObject (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject) obj .

```
    XmlObject obj;
    ...
    obj.toString(); //<xml-fragment>n2</xml-fragement>
    // content ="n2"
    String content = obj.toString().substring(14, obj.length() - 15)
```

What is the right way to store "n2" in content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [javadoc for SimpleValue](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/SimpleValue.html) - "All XmlObject implementations can be coerced to SimpleValue"

So the correct approach would be:

```
//to get the string value
((SimpleValue)obj).getStringValue();
//to set the string value
((SimpleValue)obj).setStringValue("n2");
```

Comment: why did you set the value "n2" . I would like to get that value . For me the first answer without the edit was correct

Comment: Sorry, I thought I gave the wrong answer as you say "What is the right way to store" - I thought I had misread the question. In any case - have added both in there.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Xml-Fragment");
```

And there you have your nodelist, to take whatever you want from.

Comment: thank you for this useful answer. I used the other one since it was shorter